# Need to extract some values from json

Tags: c#, json, winforms, json.net

I am trying to get some values from json but can't figure it out here is the json string , need to extract shortcode values

check the json string file :[json string](http://www.itsitus.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/json.txt)

I am using Newtonsoft for C# winforms !

Comment: Where is the JSON you are trying to extract? In a file on the hard drive? From a web service? What have you tried?

Comment: @GabrielLuci
I am downloading the json fom web, check the link above this is the string I already downloaded !

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried and tell us where it doesn't work?

Comment: Can you share the code of using newtonsoft and tell us what issue you are facing ?

Comment: OMG, i just had a look at the json, its a mess

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya  here is what I made, but don't know is that the correct directory of shortcode values or not. : 

   JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(filteredOuterhtml));
                            JObject o = JObject.Parse(filteredOuterhtml);
                            //    string idValue = o["entry_data"]["ProfilePage"][0]["graphql"]["user"]["id"].ToString();
                            o["entry_data"]["ProfilePage"]["0"]["graphql"]["user"]["edge_flexix_video_timeline"]["edge_owner_to_timeline_media"];

Comment: @TheGeneral I am using http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ to arrange the string and check the shortcode values, you can copy the json string and paste it there to beautify it

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Comment: Please, don't post "take json here". Or comments. Update your question with JSON you're trying to use.

Comment: Convert to to `C#` classes using the Online service of [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/). Push *Generate with Quicktype*. The JSON can be parsed correctly, you should be good to go.

Comment: @jimi not sure if it will help that much, i think there are dictionaries, and will create 100;s of classes

Comment: i tried...it's a mess.  we need a minimal sample

Comment: @TheGeneral  I gave it a second look. Quicktype generates quite a good result out of this, well, *thing*. It's just a lot of data in a lot of different sub-classes with many unused fields/properties. The Quicktype result is much alike the Online JSon viewer that the OP linked. I've seen worse than this. I think it's usable, with some tweaking/adjustments.

Comment: @Jimi Ahh ok, yeah i see.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look on this. here i have corrected the code which you have pasted on the comments. hope this will helps you to find the issue.

```
        JObject o = JObject.Parse(filteredOuterhtml);
        string idValue = o["entry_data"]["ProfilePage"][0]["graphql"]["user"]["id"].ToString();
        var edges = o["entry_data"]["ProfilePage"][0]["graphql"]["user"]["edge_owner_to_timeline_media"]["edges"];
        foreach (var edge in edges)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(edge["node"]["shortcode"]);
        }
```

You can get `shortcode` using LINQ

```
        var shortcodes = o["entry_data"]["ProfilePage"][0]["graphql"]["user"]["edge_owner_to_timeline_media"]["edges"].Select(x => x["node"]["shortcode"]).ToArray();
```

Comment: edge is a an array, would you let me know how I can loop inside this array!